# MVC, MVP, MVVM model in android

Tags: android

There are 3 basic design partern MVC, MVP, MVVM in Android, each model which has own strengths.but I don't know which is better?
Can every one suggest me ?
Thanks all.

Comment: MVP and MVVM. The MVP is a bit tricky to unit test in Android because the Activity is both the Controller and View. After all, all of them are good than not using any of them.

Comment: Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's depends on what type of project are you making. For the small scale and middle scale project the MVP model is perfect suit. but if you are making project like shopping site for example like flipkart, Snapdeal than the MVVM is perfect suit.

Comment: Thanks your answer.